How to implement it correctly MediaPlayer (jetpack compose)
I'm trying to implement a media player with the ability to stop and start audio when the app goes into the background, but it doesn't work as expected... When the app comes back, the music doesn't play again. I think this is because my copy of the media player doesn't survive the app going into the background, can you tell me what I can do about it?
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
class MainActivity : ComponentActivity() {
private val mediaService = MediaPlayerService(this)

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    mediaService.createMedia()
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

    setContent {
        MinimathTheme {
            val dependencies = Dependencies(this)
            val navController = rememberNavController()

            SplashScreen(dependencies.userService, dependencies.authService) {
                Scaffold {
                    AppNavigationGraph(dependencies, navController, mediaService)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

override fun onResume() {
    super.onResume()
    mediaService.startMedia()
}

override fun onPause() {
    super.onPause()
    mediaService.stopMedia()
}

MediaPlayerService code:
class MediaPlayerService(private val context: Context) {

private var mainMusic = MediaPlayer()

fun createMedia() {
    mainMusic = MediaPlayer.create(context, R.raw.mainbg)
}

fun startMedia() {
    if (!mainMusic.isPlaying) {
        mainMusic.start()
    }
}

fun stopMedia() {
    if (mainMusic.isPlaying) {
        mainMusic.stop()
    }
}


refer https://developer.android.com/media/implement/playback-app

can you post the code of composable, where you are playing the video?

I suppose you are using Jetpack Compose for the player as well , so you can use following code to detect whether its going in BG or FG.
There is no need to declare it globally, because remember{} is also used to save it from lifecycle changes.
@Composable
fun VideoPlayer(lifecycleOwner: LifecycleOwner = LocalLifecycleOwner.current) {
    val context = LocalContext.current
    var videoPlayer by remember { mutableStateOf<ExoPlayer?>(null) }

    /**
     * This runs for 1 time only for lifecycle of this compose
     */
    DisposableEffect(lifecycleOwner) {
        val exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(context).build().also { playerInstance ->
            val mediaItem = MediaItem.Builder()
                .setUri(Uri.parse("URL"))
                .setMimeType("video/mp4")
                .build()
            playerInstance.setMediaItem(mediaItem)
            playerInstance.prepare()
            playerInstance.playWhenReady = true
        }
        videoPlayer = exoPlayer

  //// This is the code you are looking for

        val observer = LifecycleEventObserver { _, event ->
            when (event) {
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_PAUSE -> exoPlayer.playWhenReady = false
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_RESUME -> exoPlayer.playWhenReady = true
                Lifecycle.Event.ON_STOP -> {
                    exoPlayer.release()
                    videoPlayer = null
                }

                else -> {}
            }
        }
        lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.addObserver(observer)

        // release player when this compose gets disposed
        onDispose {
            lifecycleOwner.lifecycle.removeObserver(observer)
            exoPlayer.release()
        }
    }

    // other code


The code you wrote plays the video locally in some part of the application, but I need a service for global management of AUDIO files

Correct make more generalized solution
